# NOT Flask: ImportError: No module named app

Tags: python

I have a project where the main directory is called `app`. I've add an `__init__.py` at the root of `app` and there is a `config.py` also at the root.

However, when I try to call `import app.config` or `from app import config` in the `examples.simple_schema.consumer.py` or `examples.simple_schema.producer.py` directory and run the scripts therein I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`.

```
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── examples
│       └── simple_schema
│           ├── __init__.py
│           ├── consumer.py
│           └── producer.py
├── requirements.txt
```

Comment: tried just importing config?

Comment: Yes, similar error. I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'`

Comment: How are you running the script ?

Comment: The run button in VS Code. Which executes the command `/Users/first.last/Projects/pulsar-python-client-test/.venv/bin/python /
Users/first.last/Projects/pulsar-python-client-test/app/examples/simple_s
chema/consumer.py`

Comment: Where are you running it from. If you are running it from outside of app dir it should work I guess

Comment: which is the directory opened in vscode? is it `pulsar-python-client-test`?

Comment: yes that's right